# Unable to forward traffic with iptables

Tags: linux, networking, virtualbox, routing, iptables

I'm having problem with forwarding traffic with network on image:
[Network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pksha.png)

I followed [this guide](https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2016/04/the-ars-guide-to-building-a-linux-router-from-scratch/) except configuring network interfaces (On VM, LAN is provided by my Asus Router, WAN is provided by VirtualBox NAT) and  DNS/DHCP part. Appropriate iptables rules were set on VM with CentOS.
Then on my Machine 1 (Arch Linux), I added route to 172.0.0.0/8:

```
ip route add 172.0.0.0/8 via 192.168.1.173
```

Unfortunately, I can't ping addresses on 172.0.0.0/8 from Machine 1.
I can ssh into VM from Machine 1 through 192.168.1.173.
Ping to 172.0.0.0/8 addresses, works correctly from Machine 2 and VM.
172.0.0.0/8 is accesible through VPN, Machine 2 is connected to VPN so there's no problem, VM has two network interfaces and can ping 172.0.0.0/8 through Virtualbox's NAT from Machine 2.

Is there something obvious that I'm missing here?
I checked iptables counters, and FORWARD rules were not hit.

Comment: Use `tcpdump` to diagnose network flows. Also, did you reboot after changing `sysctl.conf` or did you reload it? If not, forwarding will still be disabled.

Comment: Your 172 address has a class-a mask... Class-a networks end at 126 for the first octet. By default, class-b private networks should be 172.16.0.0 /16

Comment: The 172.0.0.0 /8 network is a publicly routable network. Wikipedia shows it as assigned to ARIN. That's a huge block, with over 16+ million host addresses.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it with tcpdump, maybe this will give me a clue about what's going on. I used 172.0.0.0/8 just to check if connectivity works at all, but yes, it should be actually 172.16.0.0/16